# Hand executing a C++ vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm new to programming and C++, in my course I need to hand execute a program and show how the elements change and which ones. I'm a bit stuck on this but I think I'm on the right track. Any assistance would be really appreciated.

```
void data(vector<double> &data, int idx, double value)
{
  data.push_back(value);

  if (idx >= data.size() - 1) return;
  if (idx < 0) idx = 0;

  for(int i = data.size() - 1; i > idx; i--)
  {
    data[i] = data[i -1];
    data[i - 1] = value;
  }

}
```

The data set I'm using is:

```
[4, -6, 0, 8, -7]
idx: 2
value: -7
```

So the `-7` value is what is `push_back` onto the end of the vector

I think I've figured out some of it, `data.size() - 1` means the last element in the array and if the `idx` is greater or equal to the last element return that value? The for loop seems to iterate backwards to me.

Comment: Sorry if my English is bad, but I did not understand what your problem is. Would you plz explain it a bit?

Comment: Yes of course, basically with the values I have been given for the vector. I need to visually show how the elements change, but not through a program. On paper, I am manually trying to work out the iteration. If I can understand how the program works I can then write it on paper. That is what I am having trouble with. Thank you.

Comment: Also note that this is inefficient. The `data[i] = data[i -1];` cancels the `data[i - 1] = value;` in the last iteration.

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is to figure out the purpose of this algorithm, read this answer.

Let's first take your example:

```
std::vector<double> a{ 4, -6, 0, 8, -7 };
data(a, 2, -7);
```

The result is: `4, -6, -7, 0, 8, -7`

It should be clear that `data(vec, idx, val)` inserts `val` into the `vec` so that it is the `idx`<sup>th</sup> element and the `vec` increased its size by 1. 
If `idx` is out of range, it is adjusted to 0 (if `< 0`) or `vec.size()` (if `>= vec.size()`.)

### Edit:

Visualization:

Initially:
`4, -6, 0, 8, -7, -7`

First iteration `I = data.size() - 1 = 5`:
`4, -6, 0, 8, -7, -7` (`data[5] = data[4]`)
`4, -6, 0, 8, -7, -7` (`data[4] = value`)

(Note: here `-7 = -7` so nothing changes)

Second iteration `I = 4`:
`4, -6, 0, 8, 8, -7` (`data[4] = data[3]`)
`4, -6, 0, -7, 8, -7` (`data[3] = value`)

Third iteration `I = 3`:
`4, -6, 0, 0, 8, -7` (`data[3] = data[2]`)
`4, -6, -7, 0, 8, -7` (`data[2] = value`)

Now `I = 2`, over.

Comment: Reverted my down vote. Since answer needed some explanation as OP was expecting. Now it looks fine. +1 for that.

Comment: Thank you for your help, ill give the hand executions some more practice to better understand the algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (idx >= data.size() - 1) return;
```

Actually you check that the index isn't outside of the array. `data.size() - 1` is the last element, so idx can be the second last element at most. We will see why this.

```
if (idx < 0) idx = 0;
```

If the index is lower than 0, just set it to 0 to access the first element

```
for(int i = data.size() - 1; i > idx; i--)
```

You start with the index of the last element, and as long as it is greater than idx you continue with another iteration (and decrement it). So in your example you would have two iterations with i = 4 and i = 3. idx is like a lower exclusive bound

```
data[i] = data[i -1];
data[i - 1] = value;
```

You first copy the previous element to the current one, and then the value (-7 in your case) to the previous element. So in the last iteration i-1 will be the same as idx. And because of that idx cannot be the last element, because then the loop won't enter.

So what this actually does, is inserting value step-by-step from the end of the vector to the position idx. The last element is lost and the others slide one position up. Every iteration it gets one position more to the left and what was there before steps up.

Comment: Unfortunately this is what my tutor gave to us as a program to solve. It was a bit confusing because the tutor is using his own SDK with C++ and the syntax is very different to the C++ i have seen before.